# How to fix this Overflow Exception was unhandled / Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow ( d = d +1 part of the code )

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting an `OverflowException` in my code below.

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

```
Private Sub txtSearch_KeyPress(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtSearch.KeyPress
    Dim KeyAscii As Short = Asc(eventArgs.KeyChar)
    d = 0
    c = 0
    Dim strTitle As String
    Dim b As Short
    Dim length As Short
    length = Len(txtSearch.Text)

    If KeyAscii = 13 Then
        rf.MoveFirst()
        If txtSearch.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Search box empty.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            txtSearch.Focus()
        Else
            Do Until rf.EOF
                strTitle = rf.Fields("Title").Value
                For b = 1 To Len(strTitle) - length
                    If Mid(strTitle, b, length) = txtSearch.Text Then
                        d = d + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                rf.MoveNext()
            Loop
            lblTotal.Text = "" & d
            If d = 0 Then
                MsgBox("Keyword not found.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                txtSearch.Text = ""
                txtSearch.Focus()
            Else
                rf.MoveFirst()
                Do Until rf.EOF
                    strTitle = rf.Fields("Title").Value
                    For b = 1 To Len(strTitle) - length
                        If Mid(strTitle, b, length) = txtSearch.Text Then
                            d = d + 1 '<-- Error occurs here.
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                Loop
            End If
        End If
    End If
    eventArgs.KeyChar = Chr(KeyAscii)
    If KeyAscii = 0 Then
        eventArgs.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code and the exception in the question and add an explanation to when your code fails and what you tried to prevent it.

Comment: Never post code as an image, an image is not debuggable.

Comment: Note #2: In your question always include a thorough explanation about what you're doing, what has gone wrong and the full error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever numeric type your `d` variable is, this is caused by you trying to increment it to a larger value than what's possible for that specific type.

If `d` is a `Short`, then it will have a maximum value of 32767. If it's an `Integer` it will have a maximum value of 2147483647. Either add `If`-statements checking if it's about to overflow, or use a larger numeric data type (there's for example [**`Long`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y595sc15.aspx)).

The respective max value can be found by checking the `<data type>.MaxValue` field, for instance [**`Integer.MaxValue`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Derp : No I can't. I have no idea where your variable comes from, what type it is, what you use it for, nor what values it may hold. -- What I've explained is rather simple. If you need it to hold larger numbers change the data type.